# How to use ajax to get multiple outputs?

Tags: ajax

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data:'action=nafham_list_cats_selection&selection_id=' + $selection_id,
            success:function(results){
                jQuery(".semester_selection").empty();
                jQuery(".semester_selection").prop('disabled', false);
                jQuery(".semester_selection").append(results);
            }
        })
```

This is the ajax call I'ms ending, the following is the function that sends the data:

```
function nafham_list_cats_selection() {
    if(isset($_POST['selection_id'])){ 
        nafham_get_listed_cats($_POST['selection_id']);

    }
}
```

How can I let the function outputs two values so that I can use

```
success:function(results1, results2){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing two parameters to function you can pass the array of two values like this :

```
$results['args1'] = "value1";
$results['args2'] = "value2";

echo json_encode($results);
```

and then get it in success function like this :

```
success:function(results){
jQuery(".semester_selection1").append(results.args1); // This appends value1
jQuery(".semester_selection2").append(results.args2); // This appends value2
}
```